# extract the information from a matrix with three columns

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix with three columns

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jckdmg1p05v8lv7/y.mat?dl=0
i.e.

```
E1  E2      W
6   1464    0.36
6   1534    0.27
6   1585    0.27
8   1331    0.332
11  445     0.39
13  844     0.286
14  12      0.126
18  952     0.31
19  2376    0.32
20  394     0.22
20  399     0.22
20  589     0.22
21  321     0.22
21  1187    0.22
21  2509    0.22
22  1187    0.22
23  2235    0.22
24  2376    0.22
25  541     0.14
26  229     0.22
26  321     0.22
26  1187    0.22
26  2054    0.22
27  394     0.53
27  541     0.31
28  394     0.22
28  781     0.22
```

I used this condition

```
for k=1:size(y,1)
    G(y(k,1),y(k,2))=true;
    G(y(k,2),y(k,1))=true;
end
B=cellfun(@(x1) find(x1),num2cell(G,2),'un',0);
```

to extract links information like this:

```
1   394
2   2378
3   282
4   282
5   536
6   [1464,1534,1585]
7   2087
8   [394,399,1331]
9   1187
```

I need a third column contains the weight

```
e.i. {6,[1464,1534,1585],[0.36;0.27;0.27]}
```

I tried to use the above condition but I did not get the right values. Does anyone have idea how to do that ??

Comment: what do you mean by *"not the right values"*? What are the *right values* and how?

Comment: I did not get the right weight in some of them

Comment: I used this G(y(k,1),y(k,2))=y(k,3);
G(y(k,2),y(k,1))=y(k,3);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a possible soultion using accumarray:

```
    a=[...
6   1464    0.36
6   1534    0.27
6   1585    0.27
8   1331    0.332
11  445     0.39
13  844     0.286
14  12      0.126
18  952     0.31
19  2376    0.32
20  394     0.22
20  399     0.22
20  589     0.22
21  321     0.22
21  1187    0.22
21  2509    0.22
22  1187    0.22
23  2235    0.22
24  2376    0.22
25  541     0.14
26  229     0.22
26  321     0.22
26  1187    0.22
26  2054    0.22
27  394     0.53
27  541     0.31
28  394     0.22
28  781     0.22];
% concatenate a with its copy, columns 1 and 2 swapped regarding symmetric relations
a = [a ; [fliplr(a(: , 1:2)) , a(: , 3) ]];
%create proper increasing indices for use in accumarray
[S SI] = sort(a(:,1));
S2=[0; (cumsum(diff(S)>0))];
idx = a(:,1);
idx(SI) = S2+1;
%gather elemets for each category
c1=accumarray([idx],a(:,1),[],@(x) {x(1)});
c2=accumarray([idx],a(:,2),[],@(x) {x});
c3=accumarray([idx],a(:,3),[],@(x) {x});
%concatenate columns
out=([c1 c2 c3]);
% your example
out(1,:)
```

Comment: Thx @rahnema1  
dropbox.com/s/jckdmg1p05v8lv7/y.mat?dl=0   see the link (  some values on column 1 exist in column 2 as well such as 8)

Comment: Thanks 4 ur help @rahnema1